# VBA event - Unlock cell in protected sheets if selected

Tags: excel, vba, protected

My cell contains a validation drop down list, how do i get my VBA to unlock it if i click on the cell?

Otherwise, i've tried to simply unlock the specific cell once i run the protected macro, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub ProtectAll()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim MyPassword As String

MyPassword = "test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=MyPassword
Next sh

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WACC1").Unprotect
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WACC1").Range("C4").Locked = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WACC1").Protect

End Sub
```

Hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you have almost got the answer
just supply password to unlock and make sure that worksheet is active

```
   Activesheet.Unprotect MyPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the userinterfaceonly option to protect the sheet, but allow any programatic changes from say, a macro.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WACC1").Protect Password:=MyPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True`