# Lock & Unlock with VBA

Tags: vba

Right i have some code that i wrote using VBA recorder but i would like to add unlock sheet at the beginning and then lock sheet at the end.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'
' New_Risk_4 Macro
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'reset the last active cell'

```
Sheets("Risk Template").Select
'Looks at the risk template sheet'

ActiveCell.Rows("1:7").EntireRow.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Activate
'selects everything within the range'

Selection.Copy
'Copies to clipboard'

Sheets("Risk Input Sheet").Select
'Switches back to Risk Input sheet'

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
'Selects last active cell'

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
'Selects row with last active cell'

ActiveSheet.Paste
'Paste to select row'
```

Comment: So why don't you just add it?  What's your question?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA event - Unlock cell in protected sheets if selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332602/vba-event-unlock-cell-in-protected-sheets-if-selected)

Answer (score -1):

Done it!!

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'
' New_Risk_4 Macro
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'reset the last active cell'

```
Sheets("Risk Template").Select
'Looks at the risk template sheet'

ActiveCell.Rows("1:7").EntireRow.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Activate
'selects everything within the range'

Selection.Copy
'Copies to clipboard'

Sheets("Risk Input Sheet").Select
'Switches back to Risk Input sheet'

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
'Selects last active cell'

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
'Selects row with last active cell'

ActiveSheet.Paste
'Paste to select row'

ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
    :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

End Sub